# How can I send an array params in React Query?

Tags: javascript, api, react-query

This is my react query api scroll with infinite scroll

```
export function useGetEmployeesInfiniteScroll() {
  return useInfiniteQuery(
    [QUERY_KEYS.employees],
    async ({ pageParam = 0 }) => {
      const { data } = await axiosInstance.get(v1 + employees + filter, {
        params: {
          jobStatus: ['NEW', 'IN'],
          page: pageParam,
          size: 20,
        },
      });
      return data;
    },
    {
      getNextPageParam: (lastPage) => {
        const nextPage = lastPage.number + 1;
        return nextPage < lastPage.totalPages ? nextPage : undefined;
      },
    },
  );
}
```

The problem is an array of params. If I send these parameters, the API link is

```
https://api/filter?jobStatus[]=NEW&jobStatus[]=IN&page=0&size=20
```

The API must be like this

```
https://api/filter?jobStatus=NEW&jobStatus=IN&page=0&size=20
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `paramsSerializer` option of axios.

`qs` package is quite helpful here

```
await axiosInstance.get('<url>', {
  params: {
    ...
  },
  paramsSerializer: params => {
    return qs.stringify(params , { indices: false })
  }
})
```

You can also try `arrayFormat` parameter while serializing with qs

```
qs.stringify(params, { arrayFormat: 'repeat' })
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Indices: false  has solved my problem

Comment: Great, It will benefit to community if you can upvote the answer. cheers